# Volume of Solid Equation Set Up - $y=\sqrt{e^{x}+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I just wanted to check I have set up my integral correctly for Volume of Solid.

The region is bound between $y=\sqrt{e^{x}+1}$ and the x-axis on the interval $[0,1]$ around line $y=-1$.

I can choose which method - so, using the washer method,
$$
V=\pi \int_{0}^{1}\left(\sqrt{e^{x}+1}+1\right)^{2}-(1)^{2} d x
$$

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was hoping it was wrong and would instead be a simpler integral to have to evalute.